# How to create shortcut based app in Android

Tags: android

I have a widget that I wrote,  but it really doesnt lend well to being a widget it is just a speed/dialer for a contact.  Once the contact and number is picked I consider it set in stone...  Im just wanting to turn the widget into a shortcut to see which I like better.  Does anyone know of an example of how to do that?  I can find guides/tutorials all day long making widgets but there is really nothing out there for creating a shortcut.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saying "shortcut"?

Comment: I think he means an icon that you can put onto the home screen. Like one that you cuold make with Anycut or something similar.

Comment: Can't post this as an answer, the question was closed. Look at the [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html), in particular the bits related to LauncherShortcuts.java.

Comment: Should not have been closed in my opinion. The API Demos should get you started: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LauncherShortcuts.html